# What is best practice for using a function multiple times in a react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have component with some calculation functions and im looking for best practice for using my functions multiple times in other functions and conditions; without breaking rules or overusing `useEffect` and `useState` (or should i?).

```
export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState({});
  const [render, setRender] = React.useState(0);
  const calculate1 = () => {
    if (data.object?.number > 100) return 256
    return 0
  }
  const calculate2 = () => {
    if (calculate1() > 0) return 0
    return 1
  }
  React.useEffect(() =>{
    axios.get('api').then((response) =>
    setData(response.data))
  },[])
  return (
    <div>
      {!!calculate1() && <h1>{calculate1()}</h1>}
      {!!calculate2() && <h2>{calculate1() + 1}</h2>}
      <button onClick={() => setRender(render+1)}>render</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

1- Should i save calculated in a variable then use it anywhere? if yes, how to prevent calling calculations on each render with render button?

```
const result1 = calculate1()
const result2 = calculate2()
```

2- Should i use `useMemo` to keep calculations isolated? (calculations are not expensive)

```
const result1 = React.useMemo(() => {
    if (data.object?.number > 100) return 256
    return 0
  }, [data])
const result2 = React.useMemo(() => {
    if (result1 > 0) return 0
    return 1
  },[result1])
```

3- Other solutions?

Comment: Your example doesn't show a function called `calculate`, so it won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming `calculate()` was supposed to be `calculate1()` – in that case, I'd just do

```
export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState({});
  const [render, setRender] = React.useState(0);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('api').then(({data}) => setData(data));
  }, []);
  const result1 = (data.object?.number > 100 ? 256 : 0);
  const result2 = (result1 > 0 ? 0 : 1);
  return (
    <div>
      {!!result1 && <h1>{result1}</h1>}
      {!!result2 && <h2>{result1 + 1}</h2>}
      <button onClick={() => setRender(render + 1)}>render</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and in case the actual computation was heavier than that and worth caching,

```
export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState({});
  const [render, setRender] = React.useState(0);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('api').then(({data}) => setData(data));
  }, []);
  const [result1, result2] = React.useMemo(() => {
    const result1 = (data.object?.number > 100 ? 256 : 0);
    const result2 = (result1 > 0 ? 0 : 1);
    return [result1, result2];
  }, [data]);
  return (
    <div>
      {!!result1 && <h1>{result1}</h1>}
      {!!result2 && <h2>{result1 + 1}</h2>}
      <button onClick={() => setRender(render + 1)}>render</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Finally, if the same computation is required in multiple components, I would wrap it in a hook:

```
function useResults(data) {
  const [result1, result2] = React.useMemo(() => {
    const result1 = (data.object?.number > 100 ? 256 : 0);
    const result2 = (result1 > 0 ? 0 : 1);
    return [result1, result2];
  }, [data]);
  return {result1, result2};
}

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState({});
  const [render, setRender] = React.useState(0);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('api').then(({data}) => setData(data));
  }, []);
  const {result1, result2} = useResults(data);
  return (
    <div>
      {!!result1 && <h1>{result1}</h1>}
      {!!result2 && <h2>{result1 + 1}</h2>}
      <button onClick={() => setRender(render + 1)}>render</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and if it was always paired with the same data fetch,

```
function useDataAndResults() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState({});
  React.useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('api').then(({data}) => setData(data));
  }, []);
  const [result1, result2] = React.useMemo(() => {
    const result1 = (data.object?.number > 100 ? 256 : 0);
    const result2 = (result1 > 0 ? 0 : 1);
    return [result1, result2];
  }, [data]);
  return {data, result1, result2};
}

export default function App() {
  const [render, setRender] = React.useState(0);
  const {data, result1, result2} = useDataAndResults();
  return (
    <div>
      {!!result1 && <h1>{result1}</h1>}
      {!!result2 && <h2>{result1 + 1}</h2>}
      <button onClick={() => setRender(render + 1)}>render</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: For efficient use of `useMemo`, the dependency should be `data.object?.number`

Comment: @Adam Sure, that'd work too.

Answer (score 2):

Saving the result of the calculation like in 1 won't work because on each render the `calculate1` and `calculate2` runs again (you rightly identified that on a rerender it runs again).

Your example in 2 is correct if you want to memoise the values. Generally though for non-expensive calculations you should skip `useMemo`. There's overhead from using `useMemo` and it does make your code slightly more complex to read. You should only consider `useMemo` if the calculation is computationally heavy (you should decide for yourself).

But for your example I would just suggest:

```
const calculate1Value = data.object?.number > 100 ? 256 : 0
const calculate2Value = calculate1Value > 0 ? 0 : 1
// ...
```

Comment: Simplicity/clarity is consistently underrated